# Ruby How to get the value of a variable outside of the initialize method but inside the class?

Tags: ruby

How can I get the value of @person outside of the initialize method but inside the class?

```
class MainClass
  def initialize(person)
    @person = person
    puts @person # prints David
  end

  puts @person # prints blank line
end

mc = MainClass.new("David")
```

Comment: How to get the value of  @person
outside of the initialize method but inside the class?
Thanks in advance from a first time poster.

Comment: outside of a method, anything in a class definition is invoked as soon as the parser loads the class definition into memory.

Comment: @DAdams Welcome to SO.  I've added your comment to the question itself, because the comments are considered not to be part of the question proper (they can be deleted at any time, actually).

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Variables that start with `@` are instance variables. Instance variables are called "instance" variables, because they belong to objects aka instances.

The instance variable `@person` in line 8 belongs to the object `MainClass`. The instance variable `@person` in line 4 belongs to the object that `initialize` is called on, i.e. `mc`, which is an *instance of* `MainClass` and definitely *not* `MainClass` itself.

Those are two completely different objects, `mc` and `MainClass`. The two instance variables have nothing to do with each other.

And even if it *were* possible to access that instance variable of the instantiated object, then there is another problem: you can create as many instances of the `MainClass` as you want, but the class body is only executed once, so the instance variable of which instance should it print?

```
mc1 = MainClass.new('Harry')
mc2 = MainClass.new('Fred')
```

Should it print Harry or Fred?

And even if it were possible to solve that problem: the class has to be defined before it can be instantiated, so the class body must be executed before the class can be instantiated, which means that at line 8, there *cannot possibly be* an instance whose instance variable you could print.